# Conceptual confusion about parsing of HTML by browsers and HTML's form (syntactical)

Tags: html

Someone was trying to harass and demean me today by challenging my knowledge of HTML in general which I never claimed to have as I have only begun learning it. She asked me the following two questions:

Question 1. If I create a html page with only a string in it without writing ANY html markups in it (no body, no html, no doctype), then why does the browser still render it and display the string as if it's a paragraph?

To this, I used my best guess that the browser still manages to display it as a paragraph because that's its best guess and it makes up for the missing tags by assuming that that's what the author had wanted and thus "put" those tags even if we never manually wrote it.

Question 2. In the above example, if I write several strings in different lines in the html's source code, the browser still displays them as a single line of text.

Again, I used my best guess and concluded that HTML is a free form language and thus it won't care how many spaces or indentations there are in the source code.

However, she didn't seem pleased. Were my answers wrong? If yes, then were they wrong completely or partially and what are the correct answers to these questions?

Thanks for reading and being patient with the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1. If I create a html page with only a string in it without writing ANY html markups in it (no body, no html, no doctype), then why does the browser still render it and display the string as if it's a paragraph?
>
> To this, I used my best guess that the browser still manages to display it as a paragraph because that's its best guess and it makes up for the missing tags by assuming that that's what the author had wanted and thus "put" those tags even if we never manually wrote it.

Since, in both cases, the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` is not used, it is not found in the [last step in Initial Insertion Mode](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#the-initial-insertion-mode), and therefore the entire document is rendered in [Quirks Mode](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#concept-document-quirks).

While browsers (at least Firefox and Chrome) don't *parse* it as a paragraph, they *do* **render** a simple string the same as a paragraph **in Quirks Mode** by default. This is due to the fact that "when a Document is in quirks mode, vertical margins on HTML elements at the top or bottom of body elements are expected to be collapsed to zero" ([source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#the-page), more on [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)), so the `margin-top` of the `body` effectively consumes the `margin-top` of the `p`. Since the simple string doesn't have a margin, nothing happens. The end result is that both the paragraph of text and the text by itself are displayed the same.

[This is how your browser handles a simple string](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?Test). Pay special attention to the **DOM View**, which shows what the final structure of the document is. For comparison, see [what a paragraph looks like](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3Cp%3ETest). While they may *appear* to be the same in the rendering, the structure is *not* the same.

Now, to illustrate my point about collapsing margins, wrap the content (text or paragraph) with a `div` which has a `border` to see the uncollapsed margins. [This is how your browser handles the plain text](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22border%3A1px%20solid%20red%3B%22%3ETest), while [this is how your browser handles the paragraph](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22border%3A1px%20solid%20red%3B%22%3E%3Cp%3ETest).

However, were the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` included (to prevent the browser from entering Quirks Mode), the [plain text document](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0ATest) would *not* appear the same as the [document with a paragraph](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cp%3ETest) (the `margin-top` of the `p` element doesn't collapse into the `margin-top` of the `body` element).

> Question 2. In the above example, if I write several strings in different lines in the html's source code, the browser still displays them as a single line of text.
>
> Again, I used my best guess and concluded that HTML is a free form language and thus it won't care how many spaces or indentations there are in the source code.

HTML treats all whitespace (unless [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) is set to something other than `normal`) as a single space (collapsed). Ergo, [`test\n\ntest`](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?Test%0A%0ATest) is equivalent to [`test test`](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?Test%20Test).

> However, she didn't seem pleased. Were my answers wrong? If yes, then were they wrong completely or partially and what are the correct answers to these questions?

Your conclusions were somewhat correct, but don't handle edge cases very well (e.g. if the browser changes the font/color/etc of the `p` element).

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and the BODY tags are optional, see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.3.

Leaving them off the document is treated as of type text/html which results in white space collapsing down to a single blank; that is why words in different lines in the source get rendered on one line behind each other.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

I did not think that the browser would display a single string as a paragraph. The reason for this is, as you said, any subsequent strings on separate lines are rendered in the same block. You can check this with the chrome web inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+I). Anything that is not a tag or a script/stylesheet (or a doctype) gets displayed by the browser.

Q2:

HTML is not sensitive to line breaks.

If you are still not satisfied, then check the spec: http://developers.whatwg.org/